# Load and run an EXE file after a website loaded

Tags: javascript, html, client, client-side, exe

Is there a way to  load and run an EXE file on the client side, after a webpage has been loaded ? [with java script  or HTML ]

Comment: I'm curious to know why you would want to do this.

Comment: Hopefully this is not possible.

Comment: You wanna **load** and run an EXE? As if running existing exe at the client side cannot do enough harm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There (are||used to be) several JS interfaces for this, which are most likely blocked with modern browsers, for obvious security reasons.

So either your clients trust you and install you [FF/IE/Safari/etc.] extensions or ...

However, as for the FF extension way see my answer at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504285/how-to-access-webpage-data-from-a-firefox-extension)

in short:

> External application launching
>   according to this [post](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Running_applications) can be done as follows:
>
> ```
> var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"]
>                      .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
> file.initWithPath("c:\\myapp.exe");
> file.launch();
> ```

For IE you can **try** to run this

```
<script lang='vbscript'>
    set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    WshShell.Run "C:\program files\program\program.exe"
</script>
```

Comment: Or rather `try { set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") }` because that will only work in the "My Computer" zone or have completely disabled the security settings.

Comment: upvoted your comment. you are absolutely right. though this all approach is not to be considered as a way to solve problem anymore.

Comment: how to run the exe file with arguments ? ... this successfully run the exe file, but a cannot append arguments ... how to do this ?

Comment: @AshrafBashir according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky(v=vs.84).aspx simply add them to the string (see Example 1 and 2 on that page

Comment: Thanks @TzuryBarYochay, but I meant how to do this in FF extension using file.launch(), in your example above ? I tried to add parameters in the full path of file.initWithPath() parameters, but it didn't succeeded.

Answer (score 2):

In MSIE, it's possible to use ActiveX for that - but the user has to allow your ActiveX control to be installed/executed. If you're looking at some environment under your control (e.g. your company), this could be a way. Have worked with a legitimate "remote install" feature like this, long ago; nowadays, it's easier to ask the user to download and execute the installer (not browser-dependent, and users have learned how to do this (gasp!)).

If you mean "with JS/HTML from the browser", that's called "arbitrary remote code execution" and is a pretty serious security hole. So, thankfully, that's not possible (would you want any website to run `format c:` on your computer? Thought so).

Answer (score 2):

Something to look into is [Java Web Start](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/javawebstart/index.jsp).

This is a Java-only technology, obviously, but it essentially allows you to start a local application from a Web page, and to do so in a somewhat more secure manner than firing up an arbitrary .EXE .

A side benefit is that it allows you to deploy application updates to all users simply by updating the repository copy on your site - updates are pulled automagically.

Answer (score 1):

This shouldnt be done, if a user wants to run an exe from your site they will happily download it then run it, however if the site is trying to automatically run an exe when someone visits the site that would be a huge security vulnrability.

What is it the exe does? This may be possible to do with javascript or even server side. Other options if you really want clients to run executables would be to look at something like .net click once deployment where you can publish an executable to your site and clients can then download and install from the site, this comes with the advantages of things like automatic updates.

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer - Yes it can be done. 
Long answer - No it can't be done and its terribly bad practice.

Let me explain.

Security is the deciding factor, you can write just about anything in JavaScript, including code to launch executable, but most browsers will not allow you to launch an exe - because its obviously a huge security risk.

My suggestion, do things in a conventional way, if you require better client side support, use an applet or even active-x (but I would avoid this).

Answer (score 1):

**Legally, no.**

---

If you are a hacker-cum-cracker:
Yeah. There is a security hole in older versions of flash player (less than 9 I believe) that allows you to do this. If you are smart enough, you can exploit that and run any code on users' machine (at least on windows/mac). See [this link](http://dvlabs.tippingpoint.com/blog/2008/03/28/pwn-to-own-final-day-and-wrap-up) for more details.

Comment: That's a rather transient solution with a lot of hooks and "if"s.

Comment: Note that I started the post with a **no**. The rest is supposed to be a tongue-in-the-cheek response. After all, ifs and hooks shouldn't stop a determined hacker ;)

Answer (score 0):

No, this would be a security hole.  Web applications are only written using HTML/Javascript and sometimes other technologies like Flash which are deemed safe enough to run in browsers.  (Even though they also sometimes have security holes.)